# Accept-modal before registration

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

As a user tries to register, I want a modal to pop up with some terms before the registration is accepted. Everything seems to work until the user accepts the terms shown on the modal. When the user presses the button (submitBtn2) it doesn't react. I have tried testing with an alarm to see if my submition was the issue, but not even the alarm isn't shown - what am i doing wrong?

**Registration form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div align="center" class="w3-black w3-opacity" id="register">
        <br />
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <h4>Register</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group" id="lastname">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-section" type="submit" value="Register">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Create user
            </button>
            <input type="button" name="ConfirmRegBtn" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit" class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-section" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#submitBtn2').click(function () {
    /* when the submit button in the modal is clicked, submit the form */
    window.alert("sometext");
    //$('#Register').submit();
});
```

**Modal**

```
    <!--legal data-stuff-->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header w3-center">
                <h1>Before you create your user</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body scroll">
                Some stuff from database
                Lorem ipsum...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a href="#" id="submitBtn2" class="btn btn-success success">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give an `Id` to the form. You can specify that in your htmlAttributes parameter of the `BeginForm` helper method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post,
                 new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" , @id= "Register" }))
{
   <!-- Your form elements/existing code goes here -->
}
```

This will generate the form tag with Id attribute value `Register`

```
<form action="/" class="form-horizontal" id="Register" method="post" role="form">
       <!-- Your form elements  goes here -->
</form>
```

And use this `Id` attribute value in your jQuery selector get the `form` element and submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitBtn2').click(function () {
        $('#Register').submit();
    });
});
```

That is one way of doing it. Another approach is to keep the modal dialog inside the form and when the button in modal is clicked, find the closest container `form` tag and submit it. jQuery `closest` method will be handy. But the Id selector will be faster (hopefully better than o(n) solution)

Comment: as much as i think that you are correct, the JQuery part still doesn't react as i click the button.

Comment: Are you getting any script errors ? Check your devtools->console tab.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should insert the BeginForm inside the form tags?

Comment: Where did i suggest that ?

Comment: Its just that you wrote "Your form elements/existing code goes here". Im sorry if I ask weird questions. This is my first go at asp.net.

Comment: That means your existing code ( which will generate the form input elements (input elements, not the form tag) should go inside the `Html.BeginForm` call. So basically you can use your existing code in your question. All you have to do is, add the `@id= "Register"` as i had shown in the answer.'

Comment: Ahh okay, well... That's done, but it didnt work. Can the placement of the script have an impact?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170488/discussion-between-shyju-and-codeprog).